# Try to use NPM with ROS melodic on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I use ROS melodic on Ubuntu 18.04 and I want to also use npm.
When I try to install npm, this uninstall ROS.

How could I resolve that problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339940/try-to-use-npm-with-ros-melodic-on-ubuntu-18.04./) by [xavier12358](https://answers.ros.org/users/28095/xavier12358/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2019-12-14

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rubicks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38175/rubicks/) on 2019-12-14**:
I can't tell from your question the nature of the conflict you describe. Is it that `apt` sees some `Conflicts:` and/or `Replaces:` between a `ros-melodic-*` package and the `nodejs` package?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-19**:
Exactly. I believe the first thing to do for @xavier12358 would be to clarify what the precise problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Update: I was mistaken. Not only is `nodejs` packaged for most recent Ubuntu releases, it's also been a rosdep package since at least 2014: https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/commit/58e3227d9

So, what you have to do is a lot smaller; i.e.,

```
# my_catkin_project/package.xml
...
  <depend>nodejs</depend>
...

# my_catkin_project/CMakeLists.txt
...
catkin_package(my_catkin_project DEPENDS nodejs)
...
```

Original answer follows.

---

Buckle up --- this is a multi-step process.

First, tell `apt` where to find the node stuff. Follow [their instructions](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions), or, if you're feeling fancy...

Get their pubkey:

```
root@mybionic:~# apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key 9FD3B784BC1C6FC31A8A0A1C1655A0AB68576280
```

Point your `apt` to their repository:

```
# /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodejs.list
deb     https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x bionic main
deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x bionic main
```

And update your `apt` cache:keycode  64 = Alt_L NoSymbol Alt_L
keycode  92 = Alt_R NoSymbol Alt_R
keycode 108 = Alt_R NoSymbol Alt_R

```
root@mybionic:~# apt update
```

Next, you have to convince `rosdep` (read "lie") that there is a ROS package called `nodejs` which, for each and every ROS-supported Operating System, is called `nodejs`. This fakery requires two files, one "rosdep yaml" file to provide the aforementioned associations...

```
# /var/lib/rosdep/nodejs.yaml
nodejs:
  arch: [nodejs]
  cygwin: [nodejs]
  debian: [nodejs]
  fedora: [nodejs]
  freebsd: [nodejs]
  gentoo: [nodejs]
  opensuse: [nodejs]
  osx: [nodejs]
  rhel: [nodejs]
  ubuntu: [nodejs]
```

...and one "rosdep list" file to tell rosdistro about the yaml file:

```
# /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/nodejs.list
yaml file:///var/lib/rosdep/nodejs.yaml
```

Note that the rosdep yaml can live anywhere you want, but, given that this is stateful file whose contents affect the entire ROS installation, it makes sense to put it somewhere only `root` can touch it. Note also that, since bloom v0.8.0, it's not enough to configure for a proper subset of supported platforms --- you have to configure for all of them.

After emplacing the rosdep yaml and rosdep list, you can `rosdep update`. Now, when `rosdep` sees...

```
# my_catkin_project/package.xml
...
    <depend>nodejs</depend>
...
```

...it will delegate to `apt` the installation of the package (if it's not already installed).

---

Originally posted by [rubicks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38175/rubicks/) with karma: 193 on 2019-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xavier12358](https://answers.ros.org/users/28095/xavier12358/) on 2019-12-19**:
Thank you I try it, and it works properly.

**Comment by [elegolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/50639/elegolo/) on 2020-01-02**:
Great, that helped a lot. Despite in 'melodic' there seemed to be a change from
catkin_project(my_catkin_project DEPENDS nodejs) to
catkin_package(DEPENDS nodejs)
in file CMakeLists.txt

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-03**:
@elegolo: that must have been a *very* old package, because `catkin_project(..)` was used with the ROS Fuerte version of Catkin only. It's mentioned in [the migration guide](https://github.com/ros/catkin/blob/928c2025206e1a3f0d9d504ef5b26efe1cc95d8b/doc/adv_user_guide/catkin_migration.rst#L113).

@rubicks: why did you use the `catkin_project(..)` macro in your answer?

**Comment by [rubicks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38175/rubicks/) on 2020-01-03**:
@gvdhoorn, why wouldn't I?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-03**:
Because it's old and not supposed to be used? See [catkin 0.7.20 documentation » How to do common tasks » Package format 2 (recommended) » Catkin configuration overview: CMakeLists.txt](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/catkin_overview.html#cmakelists-txt) fi and [wiki/catkin/CMakeLists.txt: catkin_package()](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt#catkin_package.28.29).

**Comment by [rubicks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38175/rubicks/) on 2020-01-03**:
If `catkin build` didn't error out with angry messages to the contrary, I'd probably drop it. So it goes...

**Comment by [rubicks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38175/rubicks/) on 2020-01-03**:
Oh, whoops, you meant *instead of* the recommended `catkin_package`, and not the complete lack of *anything* `catkin_*`-flavored. My bad. Will edit forthwith.

**Comment by [rubicks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38175/rubicks/) on 2020-01-03**:
Fixed. I'll accept most of the blame for this one, but the extremely ambiguous (and overloaded) verbiage didn't help. They are "catkin projects" as they exist in source, but, once bloomed and built, they become "packages" --- which is itself ambiguous in that the context could be catkin, ROS, and/or OS packages. It's a confusing landscape.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-03**:
I don't really follow you, but at least the answer is now correct.